How to color an aligned item in align environment?
I have a beamer document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

We have
\begin{align}
A & < B , \\
C & < D .
%\textcolor{magenta}{C & < D} . 
%\textcolor{magenta}{C} & \textcolor{magenta}{< D} .
\end{align}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


I want to color the item C < D.

The command \textcolor{magenta}{C & <  D} results in the error Missing } inserted.
The command \textcolor{magenta}{C} & \textcolor{magenta}{\le D} breaks the aligment:


Could you elaborate on how to solve this issue?

\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

We have
\begin{align}
A & < B , \\
\color{red}C & \color{red}< D .
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have
\begin{align}
A & < B , \\
\alert{C} & \alert{< D .}
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

We have
\begin{align}
A & < B , \\
\mathcolor{red}{C} & \mathcolor{red}{< D .}
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


